Expected number of bonus wins for a specific slot machine game
I am analyzing a slot machine game for an assignment I was given.

There are two reels, one on the left and one on the right.
The probability of winning a spin is $p_L = 1/9$ for the left reel and $p_R = 1/10$ for the right reel.
For a single play of the machine, both reels are spun at the same time.
A reel is said to be complete once it reaches $8$ wins.
The game ends once both reels are complete.

I need to find the expected value of the number of bonus wins before the game ends. A bonus win happens when an already-complete reel wins again, not counting a would-be bonus win on a game-ending play (i.e., if a reel would get a bonus win on the play which the lagging-behind reel completes on, it doesn't count).

Solution Attempt:
Some notation for random variables which may be of use:
$B$ = number of bonus wins before the game ends.
$B_L$ = number of bonus wins for the left reel before the game ends.
$B_R$ = number of bonus wins for the right reel before the game ends.
$X_L$ = number of plays needed to complete the left reel from a new game.
$X_R$ = number of plays needed to complete the right reel from a new game.
So we seek to find $E(B)$. I ran a Monte Carlo simulation, and got an answer of $E(B) = 3$, $E(B_L) = 2$, and $E(B_R) = 1$, but I desire an exact analytic solution (or one that can be approximated to arbitrary accuracy).
Note that $X_L$ and $X_R$ follow negative binomial distributions $X_L \sim \text{NB}(8, 1/9)$ and $X_R \sim \text{NB}(8, 1/10)$. So they have well known formulas (1) for their expectation, $E(X_L) = 8 / (1/9) = 72$ and $E(X_R) = 8 / (1/10) = 80$.
My strategy is to note that the event space can be partitioned into three cases:

$X_L < X_R$ (the left reel completes first).
$X_R < X_L$ (the right reel completes first).
$X_L = X_R$ (they complete on the same play).

Case 3 can be ignored, since no bonus wins can be earned.
Let's analyze case 1. Note that $X_L < X_R$ is equivalent the union of joint events $(X_L = k) \text{ and } (X_R > k)$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}^+$, i.e., \begin{align*}
    X_L < X_R = \bigcup_{k = 1}^{\infty} \{ (X_L = k) \text{ and } (X_R > k)\},
\end{align*}
but since these events are independent, we have
\begin{align*}
P((X_L = k) \text{ and } (X_R > k )) = P(X_L = k) \cdot P(X_R > k),
\end{align*}
which together implies
\begin{align*}
    P(X_L < X_R) &=  \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} P(X_L = k) \cdot P(X_R > k), \\
    &=  \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} P(X_L = k) \left( 1 - P(X_R \leq k)\right)
\end{align*}
where quantities $P(X_L = k)$ and $P(X_R \leq k)$ can be easily evaluated as well-known PDFs and CDFs of $\text{NB}(8, 1/9)$ and $\text{NB}(8, 1/10)$, respectively. A similar argument holds for case 2. Using Python's scipy.stats library, I was able to estimate $P(X_L < X_R) \approx 58.11\%$ and $P(X_R < X_L) \approx 40.75\%$, which seems intuitive/fine given $p_L > p_R$.
Now, note that $E(B_L) >= 0$ and $E(B_R) = 0$; bonus wins on the right reel are impossible, so it suffices to analyze $E(B_L)$. My basic idea is that, noting that $B_L = (X_R - X_L - 1) p_L$ (number of opportunities for a bonus win times probability of bonus win), we have:
\begin{align*}
E(B_L) &= E(B_L | X_L < X_R) = E( (X_R - X_L - 1) p_L | X_R > X_L).
\end{align*}
I am more or less stuck here. My ideas are:

Can I replace $X_L$ in the above formula with the quantity $E(X_L) = 72$?
Does the $X_L < X_R$ condition tell me anything important about $X_R - X_L - 1$, besides that it's $\geq 0$?
Is there some kind of straightforward formulae or properties (of conditional expected values) that I can apply here?
I happen to know how to prove that $E(\max(X_L, X_R)) = 90$, does that help?
I happen to know how to prove that $E(|X_L - X_R|) = 28$, does that help?

My hope is that if I can simplify this further into something that I can evaluate (e.g., the sums and products of PDFS and CDFs), then I can get my answer:
\begin{align*}
E(B) = P(X_L < X_R) E(B_L) + P(X_L > X_R) E(B_R).
\end{align*}

I'm getting the answer
$$
\mathbb{E}[B] = \frac{643865593}{215233605} = 2.991473348225524
$$
My idea is to use a Markov chain with states $(a,b)$ for $0\leq a,b \leq 8$ where the states where $8$ appears are absorbing. Here $a$ is the number of wins of the left reel and $b$ of the right. This way we can calculate the probabilities of reaching the state where one reel becomes complete. From there we can add up the expected bonus wins for each case. From end states of the form $(8, b)$ the expected bonus wins is $p_L(\frac{8-b}{p_R}-1)$. We're subtracting $1$ because the last step (when right reel completes) doesn't count. Similarly for states of the form $(a, 8)$ we have $p_L(\frac{8-a}{p_R}-1)$.
My Markov chain Sage-code

UPDATE
When wins needed for completion is $n$, the reel win probabilities are $p_1, p_2$ and we denote $q_1=1-p_1, q_2=1-p_2$, my hypothesis for a formula of the probability of ending up in the state $(a, n)$ for $0\leq a < n$ is
$$
P(p_1, p_2, a) = \frac{p_1^ap_2^n q_1^{n-a} }{(1-q_1q_2)^{n+a}}\sum_{j=0}^a \binom{n}{a-j}\binom{a-1}{j}(q_1q_2)^j 
$$
For ending up in $(n, b)$, we can flip the probabilities and use the same formula. Note: we don't need to consider the state $(n,n)$ as in it both complete at the same time so there can be no bonus wins.
So the answer is given by the formula
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(P(p_L,p_R,k) p_L\left(\frac{n-k}{p_R}-1\right) 
 + P(p_R,p_L,k) p_R\left(\frac{n-k}{p_L}-1\right)\right)
$$
Here's the formula in Demos.
UPDATE 2 Another formula for $P(p_1, p_2, a)$
Denote by $W$ the wins of the first reel when second completes. Conditioning on the number of spins it takes the second to complete we have
$$
P(p_1, p_2, a) = \mathbb{P}(W=a)
= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(X_R = j) \mathbb{P}(W=a | X_R = j) \\
= \sum_{j=n}^\infty \binom{j-n+n-1}{j-n}q_2^{j-n}p_2^n \binom{j}{a}p_1^aq_1^{j-a} \\
= \left(\frac{p_1}{q_1}\right)^a \left(\frac{p_2}{q_2}\right)^n \sum_{j=n}^\infty \binom{j-1}{j-n}\binom{j}{a} (q_1q_2)^j
$$
because the number of failures of the second reel is negative binomial (and the number of spins is $n$ plus that) and given the number of spins, $W$ is binomial.
So the first formula is proved, if we can show that for $x=q_1q_2$ the following identity
$$
\sum_{j=n}^\infty \binom{j-1}{j-n}\binom{j}{a} x^j
= \frac{x^n}{(1-x)^{n+a}} \sum_{j=0}^a \binom{n}{a-j}\binom{a-1}{j} x^j
$$
This is done here.

I found this formula in the update by inspection. Worked for all $n$ in the range $1,2,\dots, 20$ (I handled it as a polynomial of $p_1, p_2$). The formula seems to indicate towards the hypergeometric...

Actually, I think it's from negative binomial (as mentioned by OP). The reels are indipendent so there is the product of two negative binomials. And the denominator comes from the infinite sum. And the finite sum comes from...?

Let $W_L$ denote the random variable repping the number of wins for the left reel when the right reel completes. So, in your notation, $P(p_1, p_2, a) = P(W_L = a)$. My intuition is that $W_L$ follows a truncated negative binomial distribution (so, it follows the same distribution as $X_L$, except for $k > n$ we have $P(w_L = a) = 0$. So $P(W_L = a) = \frac{P(X_L = a)}{\sum_{j = 1}^7 P(X_L = j)}$, where factor in denominator is to normalize (so that our probabilities still sum to one). Is this equivalent to your formula somehow, or is my analysis wrong?

If we condition on the number of spins it takes the second reel to complete, the number of wins of the first is (usual) binomial. And we get an infinite formula. (I think this is kin to the way the Markov chain does it: takes a geometric sum of the $Q$-matrix). What we end up with looks like a nice identity that should be a known one(?)

So that truncated would be  $W_L$ conditioned on the event that right completes before the left. But in your notation $X_L$ is the number spins needed to complete the left reel. So $\mathbb{P}(X_L=a)=0$ for $a<n$. We should use the number of wins of L, but for that we need to know the number of spins.

I asked a new question for the identity: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4931296/111594
